# How to Find and replace value in Access table using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table in access in which I want to find and replace a cell value using VBA code.

the value i want to find is an int and the value i want to replace it with is also an int
Any tips?

what i have tried so far only returns somethng like: "cant have duplicate value in cells"

Comment: Could you post a code example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: why are you using vba for update operations? just use sql command "UPDATE myTable set MyField = 1 where MyField = 0"
is much easier and quicker?

Comment: With regards to the `Can't have duplicate values in cells`, are you trying to find and replace on a field type `AutoNumber` or does the field have the `Duplicates Ok?` property set to no?

Answer (score 0):

The best option to find and replace a value is by using an **UPDATE** query.  You can update a data cell by searching for a given value in that cell, or by searching for a given value in a different cell.  The syntax would be along the lines of:

```
UPDATE MyTableName SET MyFieldName = 1 WHERE MyFieldName = 2
```

Or:

```
UPDATE MyTableName SET MyFieldName = 1 WHERE MyOtherFieldName = "Monday"
```